# Powershell permissions or scope limits the scripts access to windows commands

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell

I have a powershell script that automates the set up of PCs for a company. These PCs are not connected to any network when setting up and thus the script has to be manually transfered and started on each PC. The script has thus far been started with the help of a batch file which starts Powershell as admin with executionpolicy Bypass and works as intended.

However, i have created a simple GUI in C# WPF where the operator enters all the relevant information needed for the script to set up the PC. The script is then started from C# by running the batch file and it works, but there is a problem...

When starting from C# the script is not allowed to open secpol.msc to change some network policies. It does not recognize secpol.msc as a valid cmdlet. But, when the script is started via the batch file, or ISE, secpol.msc is a valid cmdlet. Below is the code used to start secpol.msc.

`add-type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms` 
`add-type -AssemblyName microsoft.VisualBasic` 
`secpol.msc` \

I get this error when starting from C# gui.
ERROR: An error has occurred [System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term 'secpol.msc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Here is the code for the batch file.
`@ECHO OFF`
`SET ThisScriptsDirectory=%~dp0`
`SET PowerShellScriptPath=%ThisScriptsDirectory%IPC-Bot-Main.ps1`
`PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%PowerShellScriptPath%""' -Verb RunAs}";`\

It does not seem that the script is allowed to change registry keys either.

I could work around the secpol.msc problem by opening gpedit.msc and navigating from there. But as it can't change registry keys either i have to solve this problem.
I'm suspecting that the script is opened in another scope when run from C# rather than the batch file.

Has anyone encountered this problem before or something similar?

EDIT:
Here is the C# code i use to run the batch file.
`string strExeFilePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;` 
`string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strExeFilePath);`
`Process.Start(path + @"\sources\StartAssist.bat");`\

EDIT:
I think i should clarify, the C# GUI opens and runs just fine on the VM from the executable. And the script also starts as it should but the script does not have the same capabilities when starting from the GUI compared to when run from just the batch-file.

Comment: Are you running from inside VS?  Try and see if executable works outside VS.  VS does not automatically run As Admin.  You need to right click VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: Can you add the C# code that you use to run the script from the gui?

Comment: Thanks for answering!
@jdweng I can't start the script from inside VS because the script must be run on a VM (windows 10). So i must create an executable and transfer that to the VM. I have tried running VS as Admin and creating new Code executables and running the exe as admin. Still same result where the script is not allowed to start secpol.msc etc.

Comment: @mclayton I added the C# code i use to run the script.

Comment: You should be able to do the same with ProcessStartInfo : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=net-5.0

Comment: An executable will not run on another machine unless the deploy machine has same version of Net as the build machine.  When Net version is not the same you have to publish and install the setup like purchase software.  If using Core you can install the runtime version of Core on deploy machine.

Comment: @Jimbot I tried using ProcessStartInfo but it made no difference. Are there any arguments or verbs i should use? 
I tried verb = "runas" and UseShellExecute = both true and false. Still same result where it can't open secpol.msc and change registry keys.

Comment: @jdweng i added a clarification to the post. But the GUI is made with .NET 4.6 and the Windows 10 VM has the same version. So everything starts as expected but the script is somehow limited with less capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the comments and ideas! It made me think in different ways. Much appreciated!

It seems the problem was in the projects Build properties in C#. I Unchecked the option "Prefer 32-bit" and apparently that solved the issue.

If anyone has an idea as to why this could cause this issue i would love hear it.